# Combine CAST and SELECT in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, select, casting, google-bigquery, create-table

I want to create a `table_2` with the distinct values of `variable` from `table_1` transforming them from STRING to NUMERIC beforehand.

My guess was:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_2` AS
SELECT DISTINCT(CAST(variable AS NUMERIC))
FROM `table_1`;
```

But this does not work.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` doesn't require parentheses. You also need to name the output column. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_2` AS
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(variable AS NUMERIC) AS variable
FROM `table_1`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_2` AS
  SELECT CAST(variable AS NUMERIC)
  FROM `table_1`
  GROUP BY variable;
```